# How was kinetic energy for a particle measured?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, quantum-measurements

To my understanding, the original objective of the Schrödinger equation was to find the total amount of energy within the system. So, for the time independent particle in a box, which has 0 potential energy, the energy equals the total amount of kinetic energy within that system. My question is What type of energy was was being created from this particle, and how were they able to measure and test the amount of kinetic energy within this system?

Comment: The Schrödinger equation does indeed find the total amount of energy within the system, but the total energy is PE + KE not just the KE. For example the 1s hydrogen orbital has an energy of -13.6 eV, and this is -27.2 eV PE plus +13.6 eV KE to give the total of -13.6 eV. So the assumption in your question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The early applications of the Schrödinger equation were in atomic physics. The principal tool for probing the energies of atoms is spectroscopy, so that's how it was verified experimentally.

But what spectroscopy tells you is the differences between the total energies of states. The nature of that energy, kinetic versus potential, is not generally accessible to experiment. But that, in turn, should tell you that the distinction is a more a property of physical models than the physical world itself.